# run the current python script with administrator privileges. without having to go through the UAC dialog box

Tags: python-3.x, windows

my problem is that the startup has a software that it sells to users, but the software needs the data that is in the registry of the windows system, so every time the user launches the software on their computer there is the UAC dialog box that opens, but we don't want the UAC box to suffer every time the user launches the program.

Comment: Well the UAC box is there for this very reason. Either the user needs to launch program with admin rights or the box will appear if program tries to invoke the admin rights.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.